# TPU filament usage for dental application?

Tags: 3d-models

Can the flexible TPU filament be used in the case of printing a dental fixture?

Filament - [SainSmart 1.75mm 1kg/2.2lb Flexible (TPU) Series Filament for 3D Printers RepRap](http://www.sainsmart.com/sainsmart-1-75mm-1kg-2-2lb-flexible-tpu-series-filament-for-3d-printers-reprap.html).

Comment: Hi, what are the requirements of a dental fixture? Is it for practical usage or simply a showcase model? Could you link the filament you have in mind?

Comment: @TormodHaugene For practical usage. Filament - http://www.sainsmart.com/sainsmart-1-75mm-1kg-2-2lb-flexible-tpu-series-filament-for-3d-printers-reprap.html

Comment: Would it require FDA approval?

Comment: @JKEngineer Nope. Just for experimentation.

Comment: So your question boils down to whether the physical properties of the TPU filament would match the requirements of a dental fixture, right?  If so, @Tormod Haugenge 's question regarding requirements becomes very germaine.

Comment: @JKEngineer I want to understand the possibility if TPU filament is good enough to test for dental fixtures and possibly customized solution in the near future for dental application before getting FDA approval.

Comment: @JashJacob, for those of us not into dental implants, could you perhaps edit your question to give a brief introduction on what the requirements are? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a Ton of issues with using this type of material. First off there is no way anything that comes out of your FDM printer will be sanitary enough to meet the requirements for medical applications. Your nozzle might even be contain Lead. Last you would need this printer to be cleaned to clean room standards. As well as stored and operated in one..

Second I have not heard of a flexible material that meets FDA requirements. (which is not the same as does not) You have to worry about even the additives they add for color. Or straight up contamination of the material.

I do want to mention that there are people who use SLA printers for dental items. I cannot say how SLA would meet food or medical grade requirements. My guess is a lack of regulation.

So a bad idea I would say...

Comment: Thanks for the input. So looking into SLA printers could take me in the right direction? I only want to see what is the possibility for dental requirements!

Comment: Yeah check out Form Labs article about it. https://formlabs.com/industries/dentistry/